# With jQuery Datatable, how do you get the search/entries etc to be on the same line

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I have copied an example from the datatable site which should put some of the controlling items on the same physical line. However for some reason they are appearing on separate physical lines. This is taking up too much of the screen space. see below

[image]
I have the following script that controls the placement

```
var table = $('#exportTable').DataTable({
    "sDom": 'flipt',//'RfliptrT',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

the "sDom" controls placement. From the website the instructions are :

Each HTML control element presented by DataTables is denoted by a single character in the domDT option. For example the l option is used for the Length changing input option.

The built-in options available are:

l - Length changing

f - Filtering input

t - The Table!

i - Information

p - Pagination

r - pRocessing

< and > - div elements

<"#id" and > - div with an id

<"class" and > - div with a class

<"#id.class" and > - div with an id and class

[Link to complete instructions](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

Can anyone see why my items are not on the same physical line like in the example?

Comment: The problem is in your CSS. Probably you need to float it. But without more code it's hard to help more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation I found that the problem only occurred when I included the file dataTables.bootstrap.js - which makes the datatable use the current bootstrap theme. As DiogoDoreto said this did not have any floats so I added the following to the end of this file and this gave me the desired results

```
div.dataTables_length {
    float: left;
}

div.dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
}

div.dataTables_info {
    float: left;
}

div.dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;
}

div.DTTT {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

div.buttons {
    clear: both;
}
```